# How do I show the total ratio on uTorrent on a mac?

Tags: macos, data-transfer

I wanted to view my total download/upload ratio on uTorrent (v1.8.4) of all the torrents I've downloaded/shared. Where can I view this information?

Answer (score 2):

uTorrent all-time statistics are not available in the Mac version at the time of writing. If you want to raise the issue with the developers, the [Feature Request area](https://forum.utorrent.com/forum/11-feature-requests/) on the uTorrent forum seems to be a good place to post a request.